# How would I go about nesting one click function inside another?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that where depending on what the user selects/clicks on in answering the first question, will display a different set of fields.  For example, do you prefer an xbox or ps3?  And then depending on the answer, a set of xbox or ps3-tailored fields will show.  I can also clone these form fields by clicking on an  "add a friend's preference!" link.  I can do the two click functions individually, but have trouble bringing them together where I can click on a link to add an additional set of fields and THEN be able to click on something to hide/show the fields I want in the additional set of fields.

my show/hide ps3//xbox function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name$='console']").click(function(){
        var radio_value = $(this).val();
        if (radio_value=="ps3") {
            $("#ps3").show("fast");
            $("#xbox").hide();
        }
        else if (radio_value=="xbox") {
            $("#xbox").show("fast");
            $("#ps3").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#ps3").hide();
    $("#xbox").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#addmore").click(function() {
        $("#addpreference").clone().appendTo("form");
    });
});
```

Comment: You would'nt, as that would probably lead to the same event being bound multiple times.

Comment: You can create another click event that you could trigger - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Can you share with us your markup for the form?

Comment: It looks like you could bind the events for both elements at document ready. If they are hidden the user can't trigger them yet anyway.